# Edit data structure code to take in two vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I have this algorithm that I want to edit so it takes in two vectors. The two vectors are created from data in a csv file and I want to compare the data in the two vectors. The algorithm below only takes in one vector containing both values that are to be compared but I want to change it so that it can take in two separate vectors and compare the values between the two vectors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Some data
istringstream str( "1  3\n"
                   "2  5\n"
                   "3  7\n"
                   "4  9\n"
                   "5 11\n" );


//======================================================================


struct Data{ double x, y; };


//======================================================================


vector<Data> getData( istream &in )
{
   vector<Data> result;
   for ( double x, y; in >> x >> y; ) result.push_back( { x, y } );
   return result;
}
```

Comment: you explained what you want to do, but what prevents you from doing it?

Comment: you should fix this `cout fmt d.x fmt d.y fmt m * d.x + c << '\n';` before changing the code

Comment: then thats the issue you should addres first: Read about linear regression.

Comment: the vector contains `Data` which has `x` and `y`. Why do you want to use two seperate vectors instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm does work with a structure that has both `x` and `y`. The most simple would be to copy your seperate vectors in such structure:

```
std::vector<Data> transform(const std::vector<double>& x, const std::vector<double>& y) {
     std::vector<Data> result(x.size());
     for (int i=0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
          result[i] = { x[i], y[i] };
     }
     return result;
}
```

This is rather expensive, because it copies all the data. Maybe you can change the code that does yield `x` and `y` such that it produces a `std::vector<Data>` instead. If you want to modify the algorithm, you just have to replace any occurence of `std::vector<Data> v` with two seperate `std::vector<double> x,y`, and each `v[i].x` with `x[i]`.

*PS* the actual issue with the algorithm is that it is working on containers instead of iterators. If the algorithm would use iterators, it would be simpler to use it with different type of containers, without the need to copy data or modify the algorithm.

Comment: @ahmadalibin you can put the definition of `Data` in a seperate header and include it where you need it